# scrapyd_api.exceptions.ScrapydResponseError: disk I/O error

Tags: api, scrapyd

when I schedule my spider then scrapyd_api.exceptions.ScrapydResponseError: disk I/O error gives error.  why did such kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

This type of error comes when your scrapyd server full of their memory space and no much extra space in scrapyd server ,such kind of problem occurs.
So,if you see such kind of problem then you should restart your 'Scrapyd' server, and then schedule your spider to run with scrapyd_api.

Reason for this may be memory leak, I am not sure about it But Restart Scrapyd server is worked for me.